# How to process and forward email based on content?

Tags: email, sms, thunderbird

I recently found out that I could forward my email that I get on gmail to my mobile phone by using the SMS gateway email address of my carrier. So, I enabled forwarding in gmail to send it to XXXXXXXX@mycarrier.com and it started working pretty well. There is hardly 20 secs of difference from the time an email was sent to my inbox, and was received as a message on my cellphone. And then, I started noticing that emails with html content or length greater than 480 characters were not getting delivered via gateway.

So, here's my question. Is there way, I could say, cut out those 100 characters that matter to me in my email and forward it to the SMS gateway? Can I setup this rule somehow? Don't tell me that I would have to use outlook as an email client, configure a rule and keep my machine switched on forever.

Comment: This looks like a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Do you have access to an intermediate server? If so what programming language would you feel comfortable in?

Comment: No, I do not have access to any immediate server.

Answer (score 0):

I forward gmail to my UNIX system and use procmail to do exactly what you are trying to do. In your .procmailrc:

:0 c
* < 768000
! joeschmoe@att.blackberry.net

You may need a .forward, too, to push the mail to procmail:

"|IFS=' ' && exec /usr/local/bin/procmail -f- || exit 75 #jschmoe"

... or some such.

If you don't have access to a UNIX (inc. Linux), I have no advice.

Brian